# Three JS Creating 3D block start position end position

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to simulate laser shooting from moving object to another moving object.

If I have two `Vector3` coordinates (x,y) in move and i need to render 3D Object start from X Finnish in Y (laser).

Something like this.
[image]

I have fixed height and depth of object, i dont know a length, i can get it by `x.distanceTo(y)`. Length will be variable (objects are moving).

It is possible to draw object form X to Y?
What is the **best practice**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a cube and compute it's position, rotation and scale like this:

```
cube.position.addVectors( x, y ).divideScalar( 2 ); // place cube in the middle
cube.lookAt( y ); // rotate cube so it faces the end position
cube.scale.z = x.distanceTo( y ); // stretch cube
```

Comment: Thank you, it is nesseasary to make 3D box geomatry? Can it be simple sprite?

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit more complicated.